# How to call Async task in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm new to Swift and hence the question, I'm trying to wrap http calls into a function to reuse, however since it takes a completion block, I'm not sure how to call it. Here's my code,

```
func httpPost(_ path: String, _ parameters: [String: Any], completion:@escaping(_ ret:Any?,_ err:Error?) -> Void){

        let headers = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
        ]

        let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: path)! as URL,
                                 cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                 timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil,error)
                return
            }
            do{
                try self.validate(response)
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                completion(json,nil)

            }catch{
                print(error)
                completion(nil,error)
            }

        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

My question is how do I call this function?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I probably answered it without completely understanding your question, can you please elaborate as to what are you trying to do ? Are you simply trying to call this method? If thats the case my answer was sufficient, but looks like you are trying to do something else, and clearly you aren't familiar with closures do you? Because your comment left me baffled :)

Comment: Type `httpPo..` and use code completion.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that the Xcode itself would suggest how calling this method should be implemented. If you tried to type "httpPo...", you should see the autocompletion list:

[image]

double click on it:

[image]

I would assume that the `path` and `parameters` are easy to understand, it issue could be related to the `completion` closure; What you could do is to double click on it, therefore:

[image]

And that's pretty much it! All you have to do for now is to fill it:

```
httpPost("your path", [: ]) { (response, error) in
    // ...
}
```